# How to set welcome/homepage for wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, homepage

first time posting question here.

I need to know how do I set the welcomepage for my wireless home network.

Something like - when you join a network and open the browser the default homepage to be my custom page. (As in some hotels and cafes)

I'm currently using Medialink Wireless N Router MWN-WAPR150N.

And also, not sure if I should ask another question here too but:
Is it possible to make a log file for all the connections established to the router (example a week log) with MAC addresses and device names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router is not a web server. This won't work.

The router routes.  It tells packets where to go.  But it isn't made for serving data, running a web site, or anything else.  You're trying to do too much with the device.

You're far better off doing something like this:
 - upon connecting, the router immediately re-routes (or delivers people) to the hosted website of your choice.  I know that D-link and netgear routers have the ability to do that sort of automatic pointing.
- then, on the hosted web server, you manage your ads and run your site.

There are places that advertise web hosting for as little as $1/month, so it's not like you need to make a huge investment.

Comment: oh, probably I asked the question in a bad way. I was not searching for a way to host my welcomepage on router. Just to make all the connected devices change the default homepage to my custom url.

Okay, anyway the thing you pointed out is quite handy. I'll try to search for it. Hopefully someone here has already done with medialink router and points me to the right direction. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've just checked my Dlink DI-524 - home router and looks like these settings are not there, you need some more expensive router to be built exactly for enterprise things like this or then load there some cracked firmware :]

Comment: Same here. I've searched for a firmware upgrade on the medialink website but its still same v11.8-Nov 18 2011.. Thought amazon bestseller router should have had such tweak.. I'll try search for custom firmwares.

and connected MAC/Dev-Name tracking log is also router firmware side right?